# How to display images in GridView in descending order in QML?

Tags: image, gridview, qml, display

**How to display images in GridView in descending order ?**

The images that I need to display come from a local directory of captured images of my serial camera, What I want to do is to display in the GridView the latest image that will be added in the local folder.

This is my current code:

```
Rectangle {
visible: true

FolderListModel {
    id: folderModel
    nameFilters: ["*.jpg"]
    folder: "file:///E:/Camera-pics/camera"
}

Component {
    id: fileDelegate

    Image {
        width: gridView.cellWidth - 5
        height: gridView.cellHeight - 5
        smooth: true
        source: fileURL
    }
}

GridView {
    id: gridView

    anchors {
        fill: parent
        leftMargin: 5
        topMargin: 5
    }

    cellWidth: width / 2
    cellHeight: height / 2

    model: folderModel
    delegate: fileDelegate

}
}
```

Please help me, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`sortReversed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#sortReversed-prop) on the `FolderListModel`:

```
FolderListModel {
    // ...
    sortReversed: true
}
```

If needed, you can also specify the [`sortField`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#sortField-prop) to sort by date, name, etc

Comment: Hi @augre, Thank you so much for help, that's what I really need